# Where is Tkinter module containing functions?

Tags: python, tkinter

Where is the Tkinter module (in python 2.7) containing all the functions such as Tk(), tk.Entry(), tk.Button(), etc? I want to make a list of all the functions in a cheatsheet for quick reference and a sense of overview/control that is not gained by the impenetrable jargon-filled descriptions. There appears to be no file in the source files of python27 that gives this, there is a suggestion online that it is a binary file and therefore not accessible. Is this so? Is there not a file containing the functions within the python27 source?

Anyway any idea of where the functions in Tkinter are listed so I can make my own quick reference cheatsheet?

Comment: And the documentation is fairly extensive if you search: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules.

Comment: I can understand your frustration to a certain degree, but you have to take into consideration, that you are using free software. It's not easy to write a really good documentation. In the special case of `tkinter` there is extensive documentation as mentioned above, you can also scroll through the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py), which they directly link there.

Answer (score 4):

### Read the official python documentation

Start by reading python's official tkinter documentation at the following address:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html.

From there you will learn that tkinter doesn't implement any of the widgets itself. Rather, it is just a thin object-oriented wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter. For better or worse, it expects you to get some of the details of the widgets by learning about tcl/tk.

#### What does "thin object oriented wrapper" mean?

The underlying tcl/tk interpreter is not object-oriented (ie: not based on classes and instances). Python, however, is highly class-oriented. To make tkinter more pythonic, the developers decided to make the interface to tcl/tk based on classes.

Without this interface, to create a frame might look like this:

```
tk = _tkinter.create(screenName=None, baseName=None, className='Tk', 
                     interactive=True, wantobjects=1, useTk=True, 
                     sync=0, use=None)
frame = tk.call("frame", ".myframe", "-background", "red")
```

With the wrapper this becomes:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, background="red")
```

### Read the offical tcl/tk documentation

The canonical documentation for the tk library that's part of tcl can be found at the following link:

- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm

### Find the package location on your disk

To see the things that are unique to tkinter such as the classes that wrap the underlying tk widgets, you can look through the files in the tkinter module. The easy way to find them is to import the module and then examine the `__file__` attribute to see where it's stored on your disk.

If you're on python3 the above will probably show a link to the `__init__.py` file, and on python2 it will probably show a link to `Tkinter.pyc`. In both cases you can see the containing folder, where you can look around and examine everything that makes up the package on your system.

```
bash-3.2$ python3
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 13 2019, 12:50:01) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> print(tkinter.__file__)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py
```

(Of course, the actual file and location depends on your version and your OS)

### See the official source files on github

The files are available through github at the following link. The bulk of the definition of tkinter is in the file `__init__.py`.

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter